# ifconfig shows Interrupt:21 Memory:f7fe0000-f8000000

Tags: linux, unix, networking, memcached

Can some one tell me what does this mean:

```
Interrupt:21 Memory:f7fe0000-f8000000
```

This is showing in output of `ifconfig`. The issue is i have a service (`memcache`) which is not responding on the machine. When i checked i found the above msg after `tx` and `rx` line for `eth0`.

machine is dell optiplex 980.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: [SF] is a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: See the other comment by @dschulz, but it's only telling you what interrupt line and memory resources are in use by your network interface and its associated driver. Most likely has nothing to do with any `memcache` issues, especially if your network interface is working for anything else at all...

Answer (score 1):

The `Interrupt` number is the [IRQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request) number used by the CPU and NIC to communicate across the [bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_bus). The `Memory` range is probably the address range used for [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) communication with the NIC. These are both low level hardware configuration values, and are very unlikely to be relevant to memcache not responding.